# Use of type 'id' in cocoa class

Tags: iphone, properties, header

I want to implement a class which can be used by two classes of my project.

One is manipulating 'NewsRecord' objects.
One is manipulating 'GalleriesRecord' objects.

In another class, I may use one of the two objects so i do something like that :

```
// header class
id myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord;

// class.m
// NewsRecord and GalleriesRecord have both the title property
NSLog(myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord.title);
```

and i get :

```
error : request for member 'title' in something not a structure or union
```

any ideas :D ?

Thanks.

Gotye

How am I supposed to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use dot syntax on `id` types because the compiler cannot know what `x.foo` means (the declared property may make the getter a different name, e.g. `view.enabled -> [view isEnabled]`).

Therefore, you need to use

```
[myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord title]
```

or

```
((NewsRecord*)myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord).title
```

If `title` and more stuffs are common properties of those two classes, you may want to declare a protocol.

```
@protocol Record
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSString* title;
...
@end

@interface NewsRecord : NSObject<Record> {  ... }
...
@end

@interface GalleriesRecord : NSObject<Record> {  ... }
...
@end

...

id<Record> myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord;
...

myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord.title;  // fine, compiler knows the title property exists.
```

---

BTW, don't use `NSLog(xxx);`, which is prone to [format-string attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack) and you can't be certain `xxx` is really an NSString. Use `NSLog(@"%@", xxx);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try accessing the title of your record like `[myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord title];`
2. If you're going to be doing a lot of this type of thing (accessing common methods in two classes) you would probably benefit significantly from either creating an abstract superclass that both `NewsRecord` and `GalleriesRecord` can inherit from (if they'll be sharing a lot of code) or creating a [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1) they both can adhere to (if they'll be sharing method names but not code.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not happy since an `id` is actually a `NSObject` instance, which doesn't have a `title` property.

If your object is KVC compliant, you can use the `valueForKey` method:

```
NSLog( [myNewsRecordOrGalleriesRecord valueForKey:@"title"] );
```